# Windows 7 connect 2 pc's from 2 networks

Tags: windows-7, proxy, routing, network-shares

I have a PC on an **'X'** network and i want to share a folder to another PC on **'Y'** network through a proxy.

I added a route from **'Y'** to **'X'** but seems like it's not working.

Example of my route:

```
route add 192.168.1.38 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.18.252
```

Where `192.168.1.38` is the **'X'** PC IP and`192.168.18.252` is the proxy I used for the **'Y'** PC network.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of the network so we can understand the structure? Are the networks in the same area or remote? Do they belong in the same network but different subnets, or are there two routers involved?

Comment: Done, forgot to add route in the proxy server as well. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be confused about routers and proxies. They are normally NOT the same thing. You may have it working by adding routes, but possibly just by luck. Without a detailed layout of the networks involved (as D.A. also asked) we can't really tell.

Comment: I have 2 internal networks and 1 proxy server. Both networks are connected to the proxy server, so i had to do the link between the 2 specific PC's.

Comment: Since you solved it, consider answering your own question below. It would be helpful for others to see how this is done. Give a complete answer with a diagram (if possible) and detailed steps.